# Merge two tables based on time

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, gaps-and-islands

I am new to Oracle SQL. Please help me with this problem by giving me solution in Oracle SQL only.

We have two tables **LOGIN** and **LOGOUT**. One is for login data and other is for logout data which are mentioned below.

**LOGIN**

```
LOGIN_TIME                      ID
19-DEC-19 03.59.33.637000000 AM 1
19-DEC-19 06.58.16.318000000 AM 2
19-DEC-19 10.19.26.039000000 AM 2
19-DEC-19 10.26.03.411000000 AM 2
19-DEC-19 01.35.56.006000000 PM 2
```

**LOGOUT**

```
LOGOUT_TIME                     ID
19-DEC-19 04.34.22.535000000 AM 1
19-DEC-19 07.52.21.568000000 AM 2
19-DEC-19 02.06.13.585000000 PM 2
```

I want to merge these two tables in such a way that I get the id with their respective login and logout times. The expected output was mentioned below.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
ID          LOGIN_TIME                      LOGOUT_TIME
1           19-DEC-19 03.59.33.637000000 AM 19-DEC-19 04.34.22.535000000 AM
2           19-DEC-19 06.58.16.318000000 AM 19-DEC-19 07.52.21.568000000 AM
2           19-DEC-19 10.19.26.039000000 AM (null)
2           19-DEC-19 10.26.03.411000000 AM (null)
2           19-DEC-19 01.35.56.006000000 PM 19-DEC-19 02.06.13.585000000 PM
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why your output is not correct ?

Comment: The LOGOUT_TIME of third row is expected to be null. It's giving me the value 19-DEC-19 02.06.13.585000000 PM which is supposed to be the LOGOUT_TIME in 5th row.

Comment: I see it but don't understand why the last login is to be selected from 3 possible logins for the '19-DEC-19 02.06.13.585000000 PM' logout.

Comment: What if one more logout `19-DEC-19 02.06.20 PM 2` is added to the table?

Comment: The LOGIN_TIME is in ascending order so the LOGOUT_TIME in the 3rd row has to be less than LOGIN_TIME in NEXT ROWS.

Comment: The LOGOUT_TIME can't be 19-DEC-19 02.06.20 PM because there is no login after 19-DEC-19 02.06.13.585000000 PM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204634/discussion-between-devudu-and-serg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your query as some kind of gaps-and-island problem.

I would solve it by `union`ing both tables, then doing a window sum to identify the groups: everytime a login is met, a new group starts. The last step is to aggregate by group.

```
select
    id,
    min(case when action = 'in'  then dt end) login_time,
    max(case when action = 'out' then dt end) logout_time
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when action = 'in' then 1 else 0 end)
            over(partition by id order by dt) grp
    from (
        select id, login_time dt, 'in' action from login
        union all select id, logout_time, 'out' from logout
    ) t
) t
group by id, grp
order by id, grp
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4767a6415133caa236b303c7824ec7f8)**:

```
ID | LOGIN_TIME                      | LOGOUT_TIME                    
-: | :------------------------------ | :------------------------------
 1 | 19-DEC-19 03.59.33.637000000 AM | 19-DEC-19 04.34.22.535000000 AM
 2 | 19-DEC-19 06.58.16.318000000 AM | 19-DEC-19 07.52.21.568000000 AM
 2 | 19-DEC-19 10.19.26.039000000 AM | null                          
 2 | 19-DEC-19 10.26.03.411000000 AM | null                          
 2 | 19-DEC-19 01.35.56.006000000 PM | 19-DEC-19 02.06.13.585000000 PM
```

Comment: When I run your query I am getting an output like this <br/>

`
ID LOGIN_TIME  LOGOUT_TIME
1 (null) 19-DEC-19 04.34.22.535000000 AM
1 19-DEC-19 03.59.33.637000000 AM (null)
2 (null) 19-DEC-19 02.06.13.585000000 PM
2 19-DEC-19 06.58.16.318000000 AM (null)
2 19-DEC-19 10.19.26.039000000 AM (null)
2 19-DEC-19 10.26.03.411000000 AM (null)
2 19-DEC-19 01.35.56.006000000 PM (null)
`
I am so sorry that I was unable to print the output in tabular form. Please help me with the output.

Comment: @Devudu: when I tested against your sample data, this produced the expected result (see the DB Fiddle link in my answer). If that does not work for you, can you please set up a DB Fiddle where the problem can be seen?

Comment: @Devudu: just in case, can you please confirm what are the datatypes of columns `LOGIN_TIME` and `LOGOUT_TIME` in your database tables?

Comment: Timestamp for login and logout time and Varchar for id

Comment: Got it just added trim (id) in the union statement. Don't now why it is treating as different id's.

Answer (score 0):

Just that you need to check the case if login is less than logout time.

```
    Select id, l.login_time,
    Case when
      l.login_time<lo.logut_time 
     Then lo.logout_time end
    From login l left join logout lo
    On  l.id=lo.id
```