# merge 2 login/logout times tables into 1 with MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two table that each one of them have user name and a datetime column, one table for login time and the other for logout. i run into same problem as my, described in this question : [Merge two tables based on time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431030/merge-two-tables-based-on-time),
with this great solution:

```
select
    id,
    min(case when action = 'in'  then dt end) login_time,
    max(case when action = 'out' then dt end) logout_time
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when action = 'in' then 1 else 0 end)
            over(partition by id order by dt) grp
    from (
        select id, login_time dt, 'in' action from login
        union all select id, logout_time, 'out' from logout
    ) t
) t
group by id, grp
order by id, grp
```

but this solution use "OVER" clause and it not supported in MySQL5.7.
can anybody help me please convert this same logic but with no the "OVER" clause and support in MySQL5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses variables:

```
select id,
       min(case when action = 'in'  then dt end) as login_time,
       max(case when action = 'out' then dt end) as logout_time
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@id = id, @grp,
                         if(@id := id, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
             ) as grp
      from (select id, login_time as dt, 'in' as action
            from login
            union all
            select id, logout_time, 'out'
            from logout
            order by 1, 2
           ) t cross join
           (select @id := -1, @grp := -1) params
     ) t
group by id, grp
order by id, grp;
```

Note:  If `id` is a string, then `@id` should be initialized to `''` rather than `-1`.

Note that the assignment of variables in `SELECT` statements has been deprecated in MySQL 8+.  You really should upgrade to MySQL 8+ and learn window functions.